# How to make a container expand to the full (dynamic) height of the containing row?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an expandable widget (using ExpansionTile) but I have a heard time getting the blue container fill the full height of the row.
The text is dynamic in length so the "title" might span several rows (I wrapped it in a Expanded).

[![Image showing an example of the list.][1]][1]

I have tried all different kind of things, but without success. Currently I create a "custom" widget and set as the title of an ExpansionTile. The title-row widgets is a row with two columns. Where the second column contains two Text-widgets. The height of the second column varies and I would like the first widget (the blue container) to fill the row height regardless.

Was that clear enough? Any ideas? Current code (nevermind the formatting and the data class):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
if (item.hasExtra())
  return Padding(
    padding: _insets,
    child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: Container(
        color: backgroundColor,
        child: ExpansionTile(
            leading: null,
            backgroundColor: UHColors.orange1,
            key: PageStorageKey<Item>(item),
            title: TitleRow(item: item),
```

And then the build-method of "TitleRow":

```dart
class TitleRow extends StatelessWidget {
final Color textColor1 = UHColors.white1;

TitleRow({
  Key key,
  @required this.item,
}) : super(key: key);

final Item item;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      FittedBox(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[Text("This box")],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 15),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(item.type,
                  style: UHTextStyle.typetitle1(context)
                      .colorWith(UHColors.black1)),
              Text(item.title,
                  style: UHTextStyle.uhheader2(context).colorWith(textColor1))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
}

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/llRp8.png
```

Comment: Can you add the code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Sure. Added. A bit messy since I pasted only parts of a larger project. Hope it is readable anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this, this is just a sample code to get you started, you can refer to this and update your code accordingly -

```
  IntrinsicHeight(
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 100.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
          child: Center(
            child: Text("Text"),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 20.0),
        Flexible(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(root.title),
              Text(
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ...",
                  style: TextStyle(),
                  softWrap: true,
                  maxLines: 3,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

This will arrange the widget as you are looking for, something like this -

[image]

Comment: Almost there. Still get some strange padding around the orange container. I'll see what I can do about that. I guess some parent imposes the padding somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this =>

```
Row(
  children: [
    IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        height: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text('Hello')
      )
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Small title'),
          Text('Large title Large title Large title Large title'),
        ]
      )
    )
  ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Already tried something similar. Gives me "BoxConstraints forces an infinite height".

Comment: Try to wrap the container inside IntrinsicHeight. Try the edited verison.